# Are there any other Git porcelains other than the default one?

Tags: version-control, git

[One of Linus's emails](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/archives/git/0504/0873.html) mentions the separation of the Git tools into the "plumbing" (usable by automated tools) and a user-friendly interface on top of the that (which has later come to be referred as the "porcelain").

He also expresses the hope that Git would serve as a base for multiple different SCMs/file management tools, which would each bring different interesting features to the table (e.g. you could have archival tools based on Git, Mercurial-style branches, &c).

Is this what has actually come to happen? Are there any other SCMs/data management tools which use the Git plumbing as a base?

I'm not asking for software recommendations or an exhaustive list of all Git porcelains. This is mostly a yes-or-no question, asked out of curiosity.

Comment: I think it is more appropriate to compare [VSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) to "plumbing and porcelain" than Git.

Comment: The closest thing I know of is [Gitless](http://gitless.com/). There may be one or two others.